# Passing a method as parameter

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass a method as parameter. How to do it?

I have this in mind:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton{

public MyButton(){
    super();
}

public void setClick( method() );
{
this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                method();
            }
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either pass a JavaScript function and execute it using Rhino in Java 7 or create a `Command` interface and pass instances of it.  Java doesn't have function objects outside of classes.

```
public interface Command {
    void execute();
}
```

Or you can pass either a `Runnable` or `Callable` implementation of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use lambdas from Java 1.8, an "early access" version is available at https://jdk8.java.net/lambda/

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass objects or primitives in `Java`, passing functions as parameter in java isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in java like in C#.
In java you you need to define interface and pass it as parameter.
Last say 
    interface SetClickInterface{
       void setClick();
    }

```
    public class MyClass extends JButton{
    private SetClickInterface clickMethod;
```

`public void setSetClickInterface (SetClickInterface click)
{
    this.clickMethod= click;
}
{
this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if(clickMethod != null)
                {
                    clickMethod.setClick();
                }
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    });
}
</pre>`